# Why use an initializer?

Tags: swift

Newbie, coming from PHP. Be gentle.

Here's a swift struct with an initializer

```
struct Book {
    let title: String
    let author: String
    let price: String
    let pubDate: String

    init(title: String, author: String, price: String, pubDate: String){
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.price = price
        self.pubDate = pubDate
    }

}

let HarryPotter = Book(title: "Harry Potter", author: "JK Rowling",
                       price: "30$", pubDate: "January 10th, 1998")
```

And here's a swift struct without an intializer

```
struct Book {
    let title: String
    let author: String
    let price: String
    let pubDate: String 
}

let HarryPotter = Book(title: "Harry Potter", author: "JK Rowling",
                       price: "30$", pubDate: "January 10th, 1998")
```

If these both do the same thing, then what is the advantage of using an initializer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case, you're still using an initializer. You're using the [default initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID213), which was generated for you because you haven't specified any of your own.

> Swift provides a default initializer for any structure or class that provides default values for all of its properties and does not provide at least one initializer itself. The default initializer simply creates a new instance with all of its properties set to their default values.

To answer the more general question of what initializes for: they encapsulate the initialization of an instance, and guarantee that you can never obtain an instance in a "half-baked" state. They're Swift's equivalent of [PHP Constructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, nothing, because all your initialiser is doing is setting the values. But, it's possible that you could have other code in the initialiser which actually does something.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include some logic beforehand you could do that in the constructor/initializer.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of a guess since I'm a Ruby developer rather than Swift, but there might be times when you would want to run more (arbitrary) code inside of your initializer besides just assigning the argument values to instance variables. For example:

```
def initialize(attr)
  @attr = attr
  puts "I'm initializing!"
end
```

In the above case I've assigned the attribute and printed to stdout. I'm guessing in Swift all of that attribute assignment is being done automatically so if all you want to do is assign attributes you can avoid writing the initializer yourself and let Swift handle it.